# Error while creating Application Load Balancer in Cloudformation... XXXXX must be in ARN format

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-elb

Using the AWS CloudFormation service, I am trying to create an Application Elastic Load Balancer on 2 EC2 instances, but I am getting an error while creating Listener [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener] as below:

"AELB-ElasticLoadBa-XDTNTTXRZMC8' must be in ARN format (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 9b18bb79-9e58-11e8-9b70-c9b2be714e80)"

I have referred aws code template and added below code, am I missing anything?

```
ElasticLoadBalancer:
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
Properties:
  Instances: [!Ref 'webServer1', !Ref 'webServer2']  
  CrossZone: 'true'
  Listeners:
  - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
    InstancePort: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  Subnets:
    - !Ref pubSubnet
  SecurityGroups: 
    - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
  HealthCheck:
    Target: HTTP:80/
    HealthyThreshold: '3'
    UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
    Interval: '30'
    Timeout: '5'

TargetGroupService1: 
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
Properties: 
  Name: 
    'Fn::Join': 
      - '-'
      - - Ref: 'AWS::StackName'
        - 'TargetGroupService1'

  Port: 10
  Protocol: HTTP
  #HealthCheckPath: /service1
  Targets:
  - Id:
      Ref: webServer1
    Port: 80
  VpcId: !Ref myDemoVPC

TargetGroupService2: 
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
Properties: 
  Name: 
    'Fn::Join': 
      - '-'
      - - Ref: 'AWS::StackName'
        - 'TargetGroupService2'

  Port: 10
  Protocol: HTTP
  #HealthCheckPath: /service2
  Targets:
  - Id:
      Ref: webServer2
    Port: 80
  VpcId: !Ref myDemoVPC

Listener:
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
Properties:
  DefaultActions:
  - Type: forward
    TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupService1
  LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ElasticLoadBalancer
  Port: '80'
  Protocol: HTTP

ListenerRuleService1:
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule'
Properties:
  Actions:
    - Type: forward
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupService1
  Conditions:
  - Field: path-pattern
    Values:
    - "/service1"
  ListenerArn: !Ref Listener
  Priority: 1

ListenerRuleService2:
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule'
Properties:
  Actions:
    - Type: forward
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupService2
  Conditions:
  - Field: path-pattern
    Values:
    - "/service2"
  ListenerArn: !Ref Listener
  Priority: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong cloudformation resource. The `Type` of an application load balancer is `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`. Note the `V2`. The one you are using creates a classic load balancer.

The error you are getting is due to the difference in the return values for `Ref` function between classic LB and application LB.

When you specify:

> LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ElasticLoadBalancer

`Ref`Classic LB returns the resource name(AELB-ElasticLoadBa-XDTNTTXRZMC8) while the `Ref` ALB returns the resource Arn which is what the V2 listener expects for `LoadBalancerArn` attribute.

Replacing the resource with logical name `ElasticLoadBalancer` with the V2 Load Balancer with appropriate attributes described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html) should fix your issue.

Comment: @Smi Glad it worked. You can accept my answer if you feel it helped fix your issue :)